# Use environment variables in docker-compose for initdb of postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, environment-variables

I'd like to have my basic database built using `*.sql` script placed in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

My SQL files look like this:

```
create schema crm;
alter schema crm owner to ${CRM_SCHEMA_OWNER};
....
```

Of course, importing using psql does not resolve the variable.
My question is now, how could I use environment variables like this?

I tried around having also a .sh file in the entrypoint directory, replacing the strings in the `.sql` file with environment data, but I always get:

> db_1          | sed: couldn't open temporary file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sedjKqYgZ: Permission denied

I even tried

```
COPY sql/*.sql /mydata/
RUN ln -sf /mydata/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

in the Dockerfile and in my `.sh` script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

```
sed -i "s/__CRM_SCHEMA_OWNER__/$CRM_SCHEMA_OWNER/g" /mydata/01_create_crm.sql
```

but this also did not work.

Any suggestions on how to use env variables for setting up a DB?

Thanks
Fritz

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam sorry, no, I did not follow any further that approach. I had to do the replacements upfront and keep the data hardcoded in the files unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Currently postgres docker images will run shell scripts found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ as well as SQL scripts. You could write something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} <<-END
    create schema crm;
    alter schema crm owner to ${CRM_SCHEMA_OWNER};
END
```

in a file called `create_crm_schema.sh` for example.

From the [offical postgres docker image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.